# Install MongoDB On Mac Os

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I Install MongoDB on Mac-os version 10.11.4. when I run mkdir -p/data/db in terminal.
It show notice: mkdir: /data/db: Permission denied.
Please help me.
What should I do?
Thank.

Comment: Sorry but SO is not the right place to ask about system administration.

Comment: Neither root nor sudo privileges are going to let you modify it. Welcome to enhanced operating system security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkdir -p/data/db` is trying to create a directory at the root of your file system.  MongoDB will try to create files in `/data/db` by default.  You dont have the rights to create directories in this location.  You have two options:

Either 1. run the same command as sudo:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

Or 2. when you start the mongod process use the --dbpath option to tell it to create its files in another location.  For example:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/db
```